# The solution of the following initial value problem is defined in the whole $\mathbb R$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution of the following initial value problem is defined in the whole $\mathbb R$?

$$\dot x=y^2$$
$$\dot y=\sin x$$
$$x(0)=1$$
$$y(0)=1$$

So I considered the equivalent problem $\dot x=f(t,x,y)$
where $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$,
$(t,x,y) \rightarrow (y^2,\sin x).$
To see if the solution is defined in $\mathbb R $ I have to check, for example, if the function satisfies the Lipschitz condition. To see that, I've checked in both components of f. It's easy to see it for $f_2$, but I don't know what to do with $f_1$. I believe I can find a constant in every compact $[a,b]$ but can I do it in $\mathbb R$ so I'm able to find the Lipschitz constant for $f$?
If I cant, how should I proceed then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the chain rule to get that

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{\dot{x}}{\dot{y}} = \frac{y^2}{\sin x}$$

Separation of variables gives us

$$y^3 + 3\cos x = C$$

The constant C is unique on intervals where $x\in[n\pi,m\pi]$ for $n,m\in\Bbb{Z}$. Notice that $x$ is always monotonically increasing, so we will pass an infinite number of these intervals. But since $\cos(2\pi -x) = \cos x$, the constant will not change across the interval.

By plugging in we get that the solution to the differential equation lies on the curve

$$y^3+3\cos x = 1 + 3\cos 1$$

Comment: And how do you proceed from there?